# vue with typescript no overload matchs this call

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Why does that error occur in the ID part of the query?

No overload matches this call.

```
<template>
  <swiper-slide
    slot="list"
    v-for="(list, index) in list.banner"
    :key="index"
    ><img :src="list.image_url" @click="noticeRead(list.id)"
  /></swiper-slide>
</template>
export default class Main extends Vue {
noticeRead(id: number): void {
  if (id != null) {
    this.$router.push({
      path: "/help/notice/read",
      query: {
        id: id ,
      },
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you lose that last `,` in your `$router.push()` arguments?

So the TypeScript becomes:

```
export default class Main extends Vue {
  noticeRead(id: number): void {
    if (id != null) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: "/help/notice/read",
        query: {
          id: id
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```